# Dynamic RecyclerView Adapter accepting any list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, generic-list

I have an app in which depending on the currency selected, I pass the list to the adapter and based on the type of list passed as an argument, I decide which model class should be used.

**RecyclerView Adapter**

```
class CoinAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<CoinAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private var coinList: List<Coin>? = null
private var coinINRList: List<CoinINR>? = null
private var coinEURList: List<CoinEUR>? = null
private var coinGBPList: List<CoinGBP>? = null

private var context: Context? = null

inner class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var coinName: TextView
    var coinPrice: TextView

    init {
        coinName = view.findViewById(R.id.coin_title_text)
        coinPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.coin_price_text)
    }
}


constructor(coinList: List<Coin>?, context: Context?) {
    this.coinList = coinList
    this.context = context
}

constructor(coinList: List<CoinINR>?, context: Context?, second: String) {
    this.coinINRList = coinList
    this.context = context
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.coin_list_row, parent, false)

    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    when (currencyUnit) {

        "USD" -> {

            val coin = coinList?.get(position)
            holder.coinName.text = coin?.name
            holder.coinPrice.text = coin?.price
        }

        "INR" -> {

            val coinINR = coinINRList?.get(position)
            holder.coinName.text = coinINR?.name
            holder.coinPrice.text = coinINR?.price
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    when (currencyUnit) {

        "USD" -> return coinList?.size ?: 0
        "INR" -> return coinINRList?.size ?: 0

        else -> return coinList?.size ?: 0
    }

}
}
```

Now, I need to support multiple currencies and so the code is becoming boilerplate. Is there any way that I can make the RecyclerView accept any type of list and then perform task depending on the list?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can create super class for your `Coin`s

Comment: try to use any ready-made solution, for example: [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to create a class Coin that will be a parent of all other currency objects.

```
open class Coin(val name: String, val price: Float)

data class CoinINR(name: String, price: Float) : Coin(name, price)
```

Than your adapter would have only one List and your onBindViewHolder method will look like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {

    with (coinList?.get(position)) {
            holder.coinName.text = it.name
            holder.coinPrice.text = it.price
    }
}
```